# Transform vertex coordinate to "same" screen coordinate

Tags: c++, directx, rendering, transformation, direct3d

I'm using Direct3D to draw vertices from a vertex buffer with vertex format `FVF_XYZ`.

I want to implement the functionality to draw lines now. When drawing a line in 3D space I project the end points to 2D screen space and use my function to draw a line from 2D space. My problem is with this function.

My vertex buffer contains two vertices with coordinates `(0,0,0)` and `(1,0,0)`. I am planing to transform this basic line to my final line with basic math and transformations.

The problem is that when I want to render a vertex to screen coordinate `(0,0)` for example I don't know how to set up the transformation matrices.

From my understanding I should end up and screen coord `(0,0)` when setting world, view and projection matrix to identity, but `(0,0,0)` then ends up at the center of the screen.

How would I need to set up world, view and projection matrices so that I transform from `(0,0,0)` to `(0,0)` and from `(1,0,0)` to `(1,0)` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly its worth noting that in projection space (-1, 1, z, w) transforms to (0,0) and (1, -1, z, w) to (1, 1).

So working on the basis you want to transform a given vertex to its projection space it is simply a matter of doing the following:

```
T' = W * V * P
```

(Where W is world matrix, V is view matrix and P is projection matrix).

You can now multiply any homogeneous coordinate (4 ie x,y,z,1) to the projection space.

Now if you wish to perform the perspective divide it is simply a matter of doing the divide by w. ie

```
x' = x / w;
y' = y / w;
z' = z / w;
w' = w / w; // or 1
```

Now you have a set of coordinates where the x,y coordinates are in the range -1, -1 to (1, 1).  If you thus wish to transform them into he 0 -> 1 space you suggest you would do the following:

```
x'' = (x'  + 1) / 2;
y'' = (-y' + 1) / 2;
```

You now have the your coordinates in the space where 0, 0 is the top left and 0, 1 is bottom right.  Anything outside that range is off screen.

Its also worth noting that the z' value you have after the perspective divide can be put into the Z-buffer.  If the Z-value is less than 0 (or is it greater than can't remember off the top of my head) then it is clipped by the front plane and greater/less than +/-1 is beyond the far clip plane.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was that I assumed what you call projection space is already the screen space in pixels. My goal is a space from 0,0 to screenMaxX,screenMaxY, but thats just a matter of a simple scaling.